# How to get Facebook Rate Limit Header using Facebook4J?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook4j

According to [Facebook Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting)

> If your app is making enough calls to be considered for rate limiting by our system, we return an X-App-Usage HTTP header. [...] When any of these metrics exceed 100 the app will be rate limited.

I am using [Facebook4J](http://facebook4j.github.io) to connect my application to the Facebook API. But I could not find any documentation about how I can get the `X-App-Usage` HTTP header after a Facebook call, in order to avoid being rate limited. I want to use this header to know dinamically if I need to increase or decrease the time between each API call.

So, my question is: using Facebook4J, is possible to check if Facebook returned the `X-App-Usage` HTTP header and get it? How?

Comment: You get the header if you get close to the limit

Comment: I've updated the question to "is possible to check if Facebook returned the X-App-Usage HTTP header and get it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a getResponseHeader method for the response of BatchRequests in facebook4j see [Facebook4j code examples](https://facebook4j.github.io/en/code-examples.html#execute_raw)

You could try getResponseHeader("X-App-Usage")

```
// Executing "me" and "me/friends?limit=50" endpoints
BatchRequests<BatchRequest> batch = new BatchRequests<BatchRequest>();
batch.add(new BatchRequest(RequestMethod.GET, "me"));
batch.add(new BatchRequest(RequestMethod.GET, "me/friends?limit=50"));
List<BatchResponse> results = facebook.executeBatch(batch);

BatchResponse result1 = results.get(0);
BatchResponse result2 = results.get(1);

// You can get http status code or headers
int statusCode1 = result1.getStatusCode();
String contentType = result1.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");

// You can get body content via as****() method
String jsonString = result1.asString();
JSONObject jsonObject = result1.asJSONObject();
ResponseList<JSONObject> responseList = result2.asResponseList();

// You can map json to java object using DataObjectFactory#create****()
User user = DataObjectFactory.createUser(jsonString);
Friend friend1 = DataObjectFactory.createFriend(responseList.get(0).toString());
Friend friend2 = DataObjectFactory.createFriend(responseList.get(1).toString());
```